# Почему проверка игнорирует значения внутри переменных?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Функция генератора случайных числе запускается по клику на кнопку и считывает данные со строк , заносить их в переменные. Переменные проходят проверку , есть ли во всех переменных числа . Если да - генерируется ключ , если нет - выводиться ошибка . В мое случае ошибка выводиться даже если во всех переменных были числа. Пытался менять тип  на *int*  но в *isdigit* нету атрибута *int* (насколько я понял )

```py
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox as mb

import random

def rand(r, a, b):

    if r.isdigit == TRUE and a.isdigit == TRUE and b.isdigit == TRUE:

        text_key.delete(1.0, END)

        d = list

        for i in range(r):
            d = random.randint(a, b)
            text_key.insert(1.0, str(d) + ' ')
            print(d, end=" ")
    else:
        mb.showerror("Помилка",
                     "В полі 'Розмір ключа','Мінімальне значення' та 'Максимальне значення' повинні бути введені "
                     "числа!! ")


def clean(evt):
    text_key.delete(1.0, END)
    entry_size.delete(0, END)
    entry_min.delete(0, END)
    entry_max.delete(0, END)


button_generation = Button(root, text='Генерувати', width=12, height=1, font='arial 15')
button_generation.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: rand(str(entry_size.get()),
 str(entry_min.get()),
 str(entry_max.get())))
button_generation.place(x=450, y=0)

button_clean = Button(root, text='Очистити поле', width=12, height=1, font='arial 15')
button_clean.bind('<Button-1>', clean)
button_clean.place(x=450, y=45)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправленный кусок:

```
def rand(r, a, b):
    if r.isdigit() and a.isdigit() and b.isdigit():
        r = int(r)
        a = int(a)
        b = int(b)
        ...
```

1. В Python нет `TRUE`, есть `True`. В данном случае `TRUE` импортировался из модуля tkinter, но смысла его использовать нет. Второе - если функция возвращает `True` или `False`, то не нужно сравнивать с `True`, просто используйте возвращенное из функции значение.
2. `r.isdigit` - это не вызов метода, это просто ссылка на метод. В вашем коде вы сравниваете ссылку на метод с `TRUE`, что довольно бессмысленно. Чтобы проверить, что строка содержит только числа, нужно вызвать этот метод, добавив круглые скобки: `r.isdigit()`.
3. Из полей ввода вы получили строки, они не могут участвовать там где ожидаются целые числа (например в вызовах функций `range` и `random.randint(a, b)`), поэтому нужно вручную перевести эти строки в целые числа.
4. `d = list` записывает в переменную `d` ссылку на функцию `list`. Это само по себе бессмысленно, к тому же потом это значение в цикле будет перезаписано числом, которое вернет метод `randint`.